# Why onClick can't trigger the delete function?

Tags: reactjs

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the delete button to delete the client, I want to show a modal that asks: Are you sure you want to delete it, yes or no.
The modal is on another component, and I thought to pass the delete function as props, but when I call the function in onClick method in the yes button, it won't delete.

ClientList.js

```
export default function ListClients() {
 const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState();
 const [userlist, setUserlist] = useState([]);

   function deleteClient() {
       const userParams = {
          clientName:
        clientName,
          country: country,
          clientid: selectedID,
        };
        
       axios
          .delete(process.env + "client", {
        data: clientParams,
          })
          .then((response) => {
        setClientlist(clientlist.filter((client) => client.id !== clientId));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
          });

  }

return(
     <div>
    <tbody>
        {userlist.length > 0 ? (
           userlist.map((userlist) => (
             <tr key={userlist.id}>
                <td>
                  <div">
                      {userlist.id}
                   </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" onClick= () => setShowModal(true)}> 
                      Delete
                  </button>
                 </td
             </tr>
        </tbody>

 
<ModalDelete showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} onDel={() => deleteClient(clientlist.id)}/>

      </div>
);
```

ModalDelete.js

```
export default function ModalDelete({ showModal, setShowModal, onDel}) {
 
return(
  <div>
    { showModal ? <Transition.Root show={showModal}>  
       <div>
       <p> Are you sure you want to delete the client?</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => onDel()}>Yes</button>

        <button type="button" onClick={() => {setShowModal(false);}} >
            Go Back
         </button>

          </div>
    </Transition.Root> : null }
  </div>
);
}
```

Not sure why the client is not deleted

Answer (score 0):

ModalDelete.js
onClick={() => onDel()}
shoud be
onClick={onDel}

Comment: I have also tried this way, and still doesn't work

Comment: ClientList.js -> 
onDel={() => deleteClient(clientlist.id)}
change it to -> onDel={deleteClient(clientlist.id)}